# .htaccess redirect path & subdomain as query parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a path to a file as query parameter.

For ex:

```
http://subdomain.example.com/helloworld/
```

Should redirected to

```
/index.php?domainParam=subdomain&param1=helloworld
```

I have tried multiple ways but they either helps with subdomain or with the path. But I want both of them to be redirected as a parameter in a query string.

Like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?domainParam=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?source=$1 [L]
```

But it is not helping when redirecting both of them as parameters.

Need your assistance to merge them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule for this task:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!app\.)([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php?domainParam=%1&param1=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava. I tested it on https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=10c846a7-5179-56ab-90f3-f1cd6474e630 but the output is not correct.

Comment: Never test anything on that site. It is buggy. Test it on your Apache and you'll see different output. I tested this rule on my local Apache and got `/index.php?domainParam=subdomain&param1=helloworld/` as rewritten URI.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Anubhava. It worked when I tried on the server apache.